# script SQL equivalente

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlite

Hola tengo este SQLite script:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER MYACC_UPDATE_DELETE_SESSION_ID_NULL AFTER UPDATE OF DELETE_SESSION_ID ON ACCOUNT
FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN OLD.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NOT NULL AND NEW.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NULL
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM  REFRDEL  WHERE  PK1 = CAST(OLD.ACCT_ID AS TEXT)  AND TABLE_NAME = 'ACCOUNT';
END;
```

y necesito su script equivalente en MS SQL, estoy aprendiendo c# y estoy convirtiendo todo atraves de Regex, pero primero necesito el script correcto, no sé mucho de sql pero me ayudaría bastante si alguien me dijera cual es el query correcto en SQL.
Gracias por su tiempo.

Edit:
Estoy tratando de crear el trigger equivalente en sql para la tabla ACCOUNT, línas arriba he colocado el trigger en SQLITE, tengo una tabla en sql que ya está creada y su DDL la pongo líneas abajo.

```
CREATE TABLE JL.dbo.ACCOUNT (
    ACCT_ID int NOT NULL,
    PARENT_ACCT_ID int NULL,
    ACCT_SEQ_NUM int NULL,
    ACCT_NAME varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS DEFAULT '(New Cost Account)' NULL,
    ACCT_SHORT_NAME varchar(40) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS DEFAULT 'A' NULL,
    ACCT_DESCR varbinary(MAX) NULL,
    CREATE_DATE datetime NULL,
    CREATE_USER varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS DEFAULT 'NotPrmUser' NULL,
    UPDATE_DATE datetime NULL,
    UPDATE_USER varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS DEFAULT 'NotPrmUser' NULL,
    DELETE_SESSION_ID int NULL,
    DELETE_DATE datetime NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK__ACCOUNT__CE2C472BF82E2303 PRIMARY KEY (ACCT_ID)
);
```

Edit 2:
he utilizado el código que me han indicado:

```
        CREATE TRIGGER MYACC_UPDATE_DELETE_SESSION_ID_NULL 
        ON ACCOUNT 
        AFTER UPDATE OF DELETE_SESSION_ID 
        AS 
        BEGIN 
         IF UPDATE(DELETE_SESSION_ID) 
           BEGIN
             DELETE 
             FROM REFRDEL 
             WHERE PK1 = CAST(OLD.ACCT_ID AS VARCHAR(50)) 
             AND TABLE_NAME = 'ACCOUNT' 
             AND OLD.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NOT NULL 
             AND NEW.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NULL; 
            END; 
        END;
```

pero me da un error:
he retirado el OF DELETE_SESSION_ID, y tengo este error:

```
>SQL Error [207] [S0001]: Invalid column name 'ACCT_ID'. Invalid column name 'ACCT_ID'. Invalid column name 'ACCT_ID'.
```

Edit3:
He usado la sugerencia de @Alfabravo

```
CREATE TRIGGER MYACC_UPDATE_DELETE_SESSION_ID_NULL ON ACCOUNT
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(DELETE_SESSION_ID) 
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED AS i WHERE i.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NOT NULL)
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DELETED AS d WHERE d.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NULL)

    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM REFRDEL
        WHERE PK1 = CAST(SELECT ACCT_ID FROM INSERTED AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'ACCOUNT';
    END

END;
```

Pero tenía un error, pero me dio un gran avance sobre como solucionar, tal como dijiste, hay que revisar la teoría y bueno sin tanto rodeo, aquí está el script que funciona:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MYACC_UPDATE_DELETE_SESSION_ID_NULL ON ACCOUNT
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(DELETE_SESSION_ID) 
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED AS i WHERE i.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NOT NULL)
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DELETED AS d WHERE d.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NULL)

    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM REFRDEL
        WHERE PK1 = CAST((SELECT ACCT_ID FROM INSERTED) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'ACCOUNT';
    END

END;
```

La cláusula SELECT ACCT_ID FROM INSERTED debe estar encerrada en paréntesis para que la función CAST pueda convertirla a una cadena de caracteres.
Gracias por su ayuda a todos.

Comment: Español, por favor. Ve a [edit] y a traduces, toda

Comment: Está en español, ahora, por favor si alguien me puede ayudar, no conozco mucho la sintaxis sql, solo lo básico.

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes. Siempre puedes darle un intento a tu suerte y revisar ;a [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) para ver si logras hacer el porting del script...

Comment: En mi opinión, estás enfocando mal los triggers. Estas pensando en una sola fila, y las sentencias pueden contener varias. Haz una update a varias `accounts` a la vez en su columna DeleteSession_id, y verás como solo te borra una. Por los nombres es de suponer que nunca ocurrirá esto que te comento. Pero ten en cuenta que los triggers siempre tienen que trabajarse para recibir múltiples filas.

Comment: Entiendo tu punto, pero creo no habrá problemas ya que apenas seremos 10 usuarios como mucho y no todos editan a diario, la idea de usar sql en un servidor vps es tener acceso desde los celulares y pc. Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te indiqué, nunca cae mal probar suerte a partir de la documentación oficial. Así al menos tendrías un intento fallido, mensajes de error y esas cosas que usan los programadores.

Una aproximación a un trigger en TSQL tendría que usar [las tablas INSERTED y DELETED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) para averiguar los datos de NEW y OLD que tenemos en otros DBMS, y sería algo como:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MYACC_UPDATE_DELETE_SESSION_ID_NULL ON ACCOUNT
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(DELETE_SESSION_ID) 
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED AS i WHERE i.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NOT NULL)
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DELETED AS d WHERE d.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NULL)

    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM REFRDEL
        WHERE PK1 = CAST(SELECT ACCT_ID FROM INSERTED AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'ACCOUNT';
    END

END;
```

Comment: Hola, he intentado ejecutar el script pero tengo este error:
SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Answer (score -1):

El equivalente en SQL Server sería el siguiente:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MYACC_UPDATE_DELETE_SESSION_ID_NULL 
ON ACCOUNT 
AFTER UPDATE OF DELETE_SESSION_ID 
AS 
BEGIN 
 IF UPDATE(DELETE_SESSION_ID) 
   BEGIN
     DELETE 
     FROM REFRDEL 
     WHERE PK1 = CAST(OLD.ACCT_ID AS VARCHAR(50)) 
     AND TABLE_NAME = 'ACCOUNT' 
     AND OLD.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NOT NULL 
     AND NEW.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NULL; 
    END; 
END;
```

Ten en cuenta que en SQL Server no es necesario especificar *"FOR EACH ROW"*, ya que la acción se aplica automáticamente a cada fila afectada por la actualización. Además, para verificar si se ha actualizado la columna DELETE_SESSION_ID, se utiliza la función UPDATE en combinación con un condicional IF.

Comment: Hola, ante todo gracias por la ayuda, intenté ejecutar el script en el servidor SQL y me dió este error:
SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OF'.
  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OF'.
  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OF'.
Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: No hay equivalente en TSQL para ese OF que se usa en sqlite. Simplemente no va el `OF DELETE_SESSION_ID`. Es más, si ya estás aclarando que se usa el IF para identificar el campo actualizado, ese OF pa qué se queda?

Comment: he retirado el OF DELETE_SESSION_ID, y tengo este error:
SQL Error [207] [S0001]: Invalid column name 'ACCT_ID'.
  Invalid column name 'ACCT_ID'.
  Invalid column name 'ACCT_ID'.
Alguna idea?

Comment: @INTERNECIO editar tu pregunta y mostrarnos la definición de las tablas que estás involucrando?

Comment: Hola hice el edit, he colocado el DDL de la tabla a la que deseo añadir un trigger en sql. Si necesitas más datos los pondré.
Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: La respuesta no es válida para Sql Server, ya que el mismo no utiliza old y new para manejar las filas que están cambiado. Esto se hace a través de las pseudoTablas,  inserted y deleted y no son una sola fila. Se trabajan como conjuntos. Se realiza por tanto, mediante joins.